# jQuery.ajaxSetup() Is Being Ignored

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

In a JS file I have this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {},
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

Then further on in the file I instantiate an object that has an AJAX call in it's constructor to fill out some values.

```
function RequestViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    (...)
    // Initalization Methods
    $.ajax({
        url:ajaxAddress + 'LoadStates',
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
        }
    });
}
var model = new RequestViewModel();
```

However, when the ajax call is made in the code, 'xml' is being used as the dataType instead of JSON. This is causing my web service call to break and I always get sent to the error callback of the AJAX call. If I move the settings inside the actual AjAX call, the call works and data is returned from the server. For some reason, the global setting isn't being honored.

My question is why isn't this working? I've used this same technique several other times without this problem.

I'm using jQuery version 1.7.1.

*UPDATE*

It seems like the problem is on line 7517 of the jQuery file. It is doing an IF statement that is being evaulated to false and is skipping over setting the correct Content Type in the request header.

Comment: Are you sure your `$.ajaxSetup()` call is being executed?

Comment: It's the first call in the file. Unless it needs to be inside a .ready().

Comment: Though not required, all your JS should really be inside a `.ready()`

Comment: Actually, you should only put things inside `.ready()` that deal with the DOM. You can drastically decrease performance by putting all of your JS inside a `.ready()`

Comment: See my note on `'data: "{}",` regarding the IF condition you indicate at line 7517 as opposed to `data: {},`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Try putting your .ajaxSetup inside a document ready wrapper.(NOT likely the cause though)
- Try using `jQuery.ajaxSetup` instead of `$.ajaxSetup`
- It is recommended that global event handlers not be in the ajaxSetup.  move `error:` to `$.ajaxError(` instead:

  `jQuery.ajaxError( function (e, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
      alert(settings.url + " Failed");

  });`

Example if you have a div with a log class (puts some text in if any error occurs:

```
$("div.log").ajaxError(function() {
  $(this).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
});
```

NOTE: when you refactor, make sure to remove the LAST comma.

Also, if you are using the latest version of jQuery (1.7.1 at the moment) you can simplify:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

to

```
contentType: "application/json",
```

EDIT: quick, dirty global handler:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(e, xhr, settings, exception) {
    alert('error in: ' + settings.url + ' \\n'+'error:\\n' + exception);
});
```

EDIT2:  SOME resources also put an empty data set sent as: (with quotes)

```
data: "{}",
```

Comment: Yep, it was the `data:"{}"` that did it. I looked in that area in the older versions of jQuery I had used in previous projects and it looks like they changed the logic in that area which is why using a blank object no longer worked.

Answer (score 0):

Where is .ajaxSetup() being called? Are you using any other plugins? It's possible some other library is misbehaving and overwriting your options.

Comment: I'm also using the Knockout.js plugin, but I don't think that has any impact.

Comment: I can confirm that Knockout isn't causing a problem. I removed it from the site for testing.

Comment: Then I suspect it has to do with the .ready() wrapper that has already been mentioned.